dir command: force output to one filename per line, full path included, but nothing else
This will probably seem to be a simple question for advanced users, but I have tried with no success.
I want to get a file list in the terminal using the dir command, having the following format: only one file per line, full path included, but no other info, for example:
/home/user/beginner/file1.txt
/media/beginner/movies/video1.mp4

But dir will default to the "names-only in columns" style.
How can I force it to instead use the output format that I want?

See Also: How can I generate a list of files with their absolute path in Linux? and here

This will do exactly what dir does, but it will print full paths instead of relative paths, including directories, files, symlinks and excluding hidden entries:
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -exec realpath -s {} +


find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -exec [...] {} +: will list every directory / file / symlink in the current working directory, excluding hidden entries, recursively, limiting the recursion's depth to 1 level (i.e. to the current working directory), passing each entry in the output as an argument to [...];
realpath -s: will print the full path of an entry, without resolving symlinks' paths

Since this will print entries based on find's output, I'd print the output of realpath NUL-separating each entry, and I'd sort the output using LC_COLLATE=C sort -z, passing sort's output to xargs -0 printf "%s\n" (to deal with the edge case of filenames containing newlines), and since by now the command has become pretty verbose, I'd also put it in an alias for convenience:
alias my_dir="find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -exec realpath -zs {} + | LC_COLLATE=C sort -z | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'"

% tree -a
.
├── dir
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
├── file
├── file_with_\012newline
├── .hidden_file
└── symlink -> /bin

3 directories, 6 files
% alias my_dir="find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -exec realpath -zs {} + | LC_COLLATE=C sort -z | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'"
% my_dir
/home/user/playground/dir
/home/user/playground/file
/home/user/playground/file_with_
newline
/home/user/playground/symlink


I have chosen this answer because it fits my personal needs the best (will also list folders, will not double the path if already present).

@Shakesbeer I was still in the process of editing the answer when you accepted it, so if you didn't see it check out the last edit, which makes the thing deal correctly with filenames including newlines

Note that answers based on find will include hidden files by default (equivalent of dir -A1) - you can add ! -name '.*' to exclude them. Or you could avoid find altogether and use a simple shell glob (which also exclude hidden files by default i.e. without the dotglob option) ex. printf '%s\0' * | xargs -r0 realpath -s or even simpler just realpath -s -- *

@steeldriver  Wow.  realpath -s -- *  Now that is amazing.

@JayCravens be aware that it's only really suitable for interactive use - for very large numbers of files the expansion of * may exceed the maximum command line length ARG_MAX. The printf/xargs version doesn't have the same limitation and is better suited for scripting.

@steeldriver Why didn't I think of a simple shell glob? :| To be honest, I think you should undelete your answer (what is even wrong with it? I can't see it), and maybe we should have OP accept yours. In hindsight, this is so bloated compared to how simple it could be.

On the hidden files thing: I was once again tricked by my ~/.zshrc, which aliases dir to ls -lSrah @steeldriver, thanks for pointing that out, I'll update my answer

@Shakesbeer Please check out the updated answer based on steeldriver's suggestion, if you want to mimic the exact behavior of dir you may want to use this updated version rather than the old version

You can readlink command for that. First run find command to get files in the current directory. Then pipe the list to readlink. For example:
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0| xargs -0 readlink -f

Which will list in a single column all the files. If you want directories instead of files then use - type d in find command.

Notably, this will list only files, unlike dir (I'm unclear on whether this is what OP actually wants)

Filenames with spaces will not be handled correctly.

It's a bit messy, but I got it in one line:
readarray <<< $(dir -1) dir_list; for line in "${dir_list[@]}"; do printf "%s\n" "$line"; done | xargs -I {} echo "$PWD/{}"

It separates each dir -1 into individual "line"s, then iterates the array, appending the echo of $PWD to each xargs line.

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just readarray <<< $(dir -1) dir_list; for line in "${dir_list[@]}"; do printf "%s" "${PWD}/${line}"; done?

This seems like a  very roundabout way to write dir -1 | xargs -I {} echo "$PWD/{}" - does reading the lines into an array and printing them back out really add anything?

@steeldriver Guilty.  It's what I do is overthink it, every time.  I'm usually trying to teach through commands.  Redundancy can be eye opening and works great for learning environments.  Case in point; this answer with these two comments, it's pure gold.

@JayCravens I've done it myself plenty of times - sometimes I cringe when I come across some of my older answers lol
